# django - translation.activate() - doesnot activate globally

Tags: python, django

I am trying to change the language of page, I have a `<select>` options with languages where you can select the language which fires a location.href change with:

```
var lang = $(this).val();
var currentpage = String(window.location.href);
window.location.href = 'changelang/?lang=' + lang + '&back=' + currentpage;
```

I did in urls.py:

```
url(r'^changelang/$', 'changelanguage', name='changelanguage'),
```

and in views

```
def changelanguage(request):
   lang = request.GET.get('lang')
   back = request.GET.get('back')
   translation.activate(lang)
   return HttpResponseRedirect(back)
```

I thought, it will change the language for all pages, but it isnot changing language at all.

I tested this by activating in my startpage function

```
def startpage(request):
   translation.activate('en')
   return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

it is really changing but only for startpage.

how is it possible to activate the language for all pages in one view?

Comment: Do you make proper changes in settings.py Middleware section? And also show you urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I didnot know that django already was thinking about me:

I solved this by using django's own `set_language()` function [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view)

pretty straightforward!